# Array of CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-freehand-drawing-techniques--mobile-15602

In this tutorial I found a line that made me wonder

> CGPoint pointsBuffer[CAPACITY];

where CAPACITY is

```
#define CAPACITY 100
```

I tried to NSLog pointsBuffer, but it seems I can't, can anyone explain this to me? and how does this useful to the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all the values, you'll need to iterate over the whole array:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    NSLog(@"Point %zu = (%f, %f)", i, pointsBuffer[i].x pointsBuffer[i].y);
```

How is it useful to the code? The tutorial explains it in Step 2.

Answer (score 1):

Its an array of `CGPoint` and you want is something like this:

```
for (int capacityIndex = 0; capacityIndex < CAPACITY; capacityIndex++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pointsBuffer[capacityIndex]));
}
```

Or to print a specific point:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pointsBuffer[5])); // To print 6th point.
```

Answer (score -1):

This an array of 100 points.

you can NSLog

if you don't assign point in an array index, it will return x=0, y=0 as default point value

```
NSLog(@"point(%f,%f)",pointsBuffer[0].x,pointsBuffer[0].y);
```

you can assign value into array index

```
pointsBuffer[1].x = 120.0;
pointsBuffer[1].x = 130.0;
NSLog(@"point(%f,%f)",pointsBuffer[1].x,pointsBuffer[1].y);
```

Comment: A locally-declared array is _not_ initialized to 0. Its values are garbage.

Comment: it may garbage but it will always 0,  you can compare anything with this value